# Aspen Simulator not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, springboard

I have googled for two days and still no luck. I am running a Mac OS X 10.5.5 and the iPhone SDK 3.1 beta, running the [Aspen Simulator](http://www.seifi.org/javascript/aspen-simulator-simulates-iphone-safari-browser.html).

My problem is that I can not get any app to work on the Simulator. It builds alright but the simulator shows a black screen and then returns to the main menu. I get this error on Xcode:

```
Error from Debugger: Failed to launch simulated application. See console.
```

and in console, it says something about "unable to find springboard (bootstrap lookup error".

Can you please help me?

Comment: The iPhone SDK 3.1 is quite old. Why are you using a **beta** version, while we are currently running an iOS SDK 4.3.3 **stable** and an iOS SDK 5.0 **beta**?

Comment: I know but is there no support for old sdks.? I have been trying very hard but my laptop specs does not allow for a much heavier system. its already dead-slow.

Comment: In the latest production Xcode you have support for iOS SDK 4.* and for iOS 3.2, using which you'll be able to test almost completely the functionalities of iOS < 4. By the way I would not recommend using a very old beta version for testing apps.

Comment: Hmmmm. So you would of course recommend updating. BTW, which Mac OS and Iphone sdk version is the best in terms of support and performance?

Comment: The latest stable releases, always. By the way, performance will depend on your hardware, so it's not so simple to answer. I do not think you will be able to release today an app developed with a beta SDK from the past. You should contact Apple about this issue.

Comment: OK. Thank You for the very fast replies

Comment: I'll prepare an answer for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should think about updating your system. Using an old iPhone SDK 3.1 beta nowadays is really strange, you should update to the latest stable iOS SDK 4.3.3 and test backwards compatibility of your app using the built in iOS SDK 3.2 from iPad. This will help you test the app on this older SDK while getting active support from both Apple and developers.

Tell me if updating solves your issues or not. Thank you!

Comment: OK tell me one more thing. I have MAC OS 10.5.5. Do i need to update to snow leopard in order for ios SDK 4.3.3 to work?